# Alfresco properties encryption

Tags: encryption, alfresco

I want to encrypt some specific property of a file like encryption type password decryption key these are custom properties.Can anyone tell How can i encrypt those properties?

Comment: How shall be able to read/write these properties? Only a specific user? Everybody?

Comment: i am using node service and for everybody user need not be specific it may be or not

Answer (score 0):

The same way you encrypt any other data. Find some way to convert the various data into a buffer stream of formatted data (XML/TLV/etc.) and encrypt the buffer. Data is data.

That being said, if you're looking to transport this data along with the file, **don't**. That defeats the entire purpose of encryption. It **only** works if you do not send keys (except maybe public keys), passwords, etc along with the data. Rule #1 of encryption is keep your private keys private.

If there were a magic way to do this securely, we wouldn't need PKI.

Answer (score -1):

Hello everyone now i am able to answer my question,
In Alfresco there is a bean name metadetaEncryptor inject that and use to encrypt and decrypt the data. by default it will use your alfresco keystore for key.

Want more info then comment below..............!!